# Make formula depend on key word entered in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to know how to get a set of cells to auto generate a specific date when another cell has been entered with one of four specific key words. (Key words: `AFAM`, `AFCM`, `MSM`, `MSM/FW`)

Ex. If `AFAM` is entered into cell A1, cells C1, D1, and E1 will automatically generate a 'date' based off the date entered into B1. note: Cells C1, D1, and E1 will have different dates based off of cell B1.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to understand what you're looking for.  It would help if your add examples to your question -- what results go in C1, D1, and E1 for each keyword.  If it's more complicated than that, explain the logic to get fromn keyword to result.

Comment: Is the main thing you're missing the "turn AFAM etc. into a date as in 2015-12-24"-part? If so, check out the built in help on the LOOKUP function.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is pretty vague, so here's a pretty vague answer that will hopefully get you on the right track.

In each cell C1, D1, and E1, your formula will have to include some check for the value in A1. You can use the following formula construction and fill in the specifics for your project (i.e., replace the parts of the formula in `<...>`).

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"AFAM","AFCM","MSM","MSM/FW"},0),<Do this if "AFAM">,<Do this if "AFCM">,<Do this if "MSM">,<Do this if "MSM/FW">),<Do this if A1 matches none of the codes>)
```

This is just one way to go about this. Without knowing specifically what you want, it's impossible to say if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

1. put a data validation pull-down in **A1**
2. put some date in **B1**
3. put `=10*COLUMNS($A:A)+LOOKUP($A$1,{"AFAM","AFCM","MSM","MSM/FW"},{1,2,3,4})+$B$1` in **C1**
4. copy **C1** to **D1** and **E1**

[image]